# how to get a date of next month

Tags: .net, vb.net

how to get a date of next month (MM/20/YYYY) using current date, I have tried but ends an error, Please advice

```
      Dim today = Date.Today
        Dim year = Convert.ToInt32(today.AddYears(1).ToString())
        Dim month = Convert.ToInt32(today.AddMonths(1).ToString())

        Dim newDateTime As Date = New DateTime(year, month, 20)
```

Comment: What's with the String-Integer-Date conversions? Isn't `Dim now = Date.Today Dim nextMonth = now.AddMonths(1)` enough? Does it not behave the way you want? The outcome is based on the current culture's calendar.

Comment: dim newdatetime as Date = new Datetime(integer(year),integer(month),interger(Day)) so i need to convert the year and month as Integer

Comment: Of course, your question doesn't show getting a date next month; it shows getting the date on the twentieth of next month a year from now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The year and month variables are `Dates` not `Integers`.  The
  `Convert` is failing due to this.
- The `Date` object has a `Year` and `Month` property you can use.
- The conversion code is also not needed.

**Sample Code**

```
Dim today = Date.Today
Dim newDateTime = New Date(today.AddYears(1).Year, today.AddMonths(1).Month, 20)
```

Comment: There's a logic error in it, too. What if it's december? Then the year will be the next year, but the month will be 1, whereas the actual date for the current date plus one year _and_ one month would have a year value that's two higher.

Comment: Yes, there could be several issues with this logic.  For example if the day changes from 20 to 31 then we could have issues with months not having 31 days.  The question is dealing with basic syntax issues and I addressed that without addressing the logic issues that the question did not ask about.